# Помогите решить специфическую задачу по шифрованию папки/раздела (RaspberryPi)

Tags: linux, шифрование, raspberry-pi, криптография

Возникла определенная задача, суть которой состоит в следующем:
Я имею флешку с записанным образом для RaspberryPi4 (Расбериан 11) и в домашней  директории (/home/pi) есть папка с моими данными (/home/pi/myDir) и программами.

Я хочу сделать следующее: зашифровать данный каталог с моей информацией, и если кто-то возьмет мою флешку и вставит в ноут, он не смог получить доступ к папке, только если введет пароль для декриптирования папки. Но, мне **также нужно сделать**, чтобы при запуске RPI4 с этой флешкой, плата автоматически могла декриптировать данную папку и в дальнейшем осуществлялся заданный мной скрипт (автозапуск моего ПО и т.п.)
Итак, есть ли возможность как-то реализовать данную затею?
Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Владислав, пожалуйста, исправьте `спецефическую` на `специфическую`

Comment: Раз может расшифровать сама автоматически - значит, незапароленные ключи где-то рядом на этой же флешке. С понятными последствиями.

Comment: @user_587 ключи на другую флешку надо положить

Answer (score 0):

Можно вспомнить что "всё есть файл", немного извернуться и сделать так:

1. Создать файл, который будет использоваться как раздел (например, при помощи truncate)
2. Разметить файл как диск об [luks и cryptsetup](https://losst.pro/shifrovanie-diskov-v-linux)
3. Ключи сложить рядом на флешку и зашифровать [при помощи gpg](https://habr.com/ru/post/659755/)
4. Написать скрипт, который будет создавать в той-же tmpfs (в памяти) временный диск, расшифровывать туда ключи (спрашивая пароль) и монтировать файл-диск куда указано.

На доверенной же машине можно написать, например, [systemd automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) юнит